# Why does Jython not enforce the interface requirements of a Java Interface

Tags: java, python, jython

In Java, I am used to compiler errors when failing to implement all the required methods of an interface.  I was surprised when I made an Object in Jython that did not implement all the required methods (getRowCount, getColumnCount, getValueAt) of the javax.Swing.AbstractTableModel which implements the interface TableModel.  From the [Javadocs of AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html):

> To create a concrete TableModel as a subclass of AbstractTableModel you need only provide implementations for the following three methods:

Jython class that should fail:

```
class ResourceTableModel(AbstractTableModel):
    COLUMN_NAMES = ('path','filename','parametername', 'parametervalue')
    def __init__(self, *rows):
        self.data = list(rows)
    def getRowCount(self):
        return len(self.data)
    def getColumnCount(self):
        return len(self.COLUMN_NAMES)
```

Testing the above:

```
 def test_column_count(self):
        e = mySwingGUI.ResourceTableModel()
        column_count = e.getColumnCount()
        self.assertEqual(column_count,4)
```

Then I read that you can use isinstance() to see if an object is an instance of a specific interface.

so I tried this:

```
 def test_column_count(self):
        e = mySwingGUI.ResourceTableModel()
        if isinstance(e,javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel):
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
        column_count = e.getColumnCount()
        self.assertEqual(column_count,4)
```

but it prints true even though I have not implemented all the methods.  Is there a way to make Jython enforce interface contracts or is this only enforced by the Java compiler?

Comment: AbstractTableModel is not an interface.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Stultuske.   I think I may have to change the wording of my question.  Still, AbstractTableModel implements TableModel and my code doesn't meet the requirements for AbstractTableModel in the docs:  "To create a concrete TableModel as a subclass of AbstractTableModel you need only provide implementations for the following three methods"

Comment: when I try similar code in java I get the compiler error:  TimTableModel.java:3: error: TimTableModel is not abstract and does not override abstract method getValueAt(int,int) in TableMode
public class TimTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{